# Downloading only AWS S3 object file names and image URL in CSV Format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have hosted files in AWS s3 bucket, I need only all S3 bucket object URL's  in CSV file

Please suggest

Comment: `S3 Inventory` or multiple list requests until all objects and prefixes are listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all S3 Object URLS by using the AWS SDK for S3. First, what you need to do is read all items in a bucket. You can use Python code similar to this Java code (you can port the logic):

```
 ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest
                    .builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

ListObjectsResponse res = s3.listObjects(listObjects);
List<S3Object> objects = res.contents();

for (ListIterator iterVals = objects.listIterator(); iterVals.hasNext(); ) {
 
     S3Object myValue = (S3Object) iterVals.next();                  
     System.out.print("\n The name of the key is " + myValue.key());
}
```

Then iterate through the list and get the key as shown above. For each object, you can get the URL using Python code similar to this:

```
  GetUrlRequest request = GetUrlRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(keyName)
                    .build();

 URL url = s3.utilities().getUrl(request);
 System.out.println("The URL for  "+keyName +" is "+url.toString());
```

Put each URL value into a collection and then write the collection out to a CSV. That is how you achieve your use case.